# Python Flask, nginx, gunicorn - unable to upload files larger than 8KB - "403 Forbidden" error

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Python Flask application running on AWS that used to work a year ago but not does not let me upload files over 8040 bytes via POST REST API call.

This is the error message I get on the client side:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

If I try to upload a file that's less than 8040 bytes, it uploads successfully. Something to do with the size.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf has this:

`client_max_body_size 10M;`

I have a systemd service called myapp.service that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance for my app service REST API
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/PythonFlask
Environment="PATH=/home/myuser/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/myuser/env/bin/gunicorn --limit-request-line 0 --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:3000 --access-logfile /var/log/myapp/gunicorn-access.log --error-logfile /var/log/myapp/gunicorn-error.log wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I restart the service like this:

`sudo systemctl restart myapp.service`

wsgi.py looks like this:

```
from appServer import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This used to work fine even with 5-6 MB files successfully uploaded but now it is not. After reading several posts here, I put that "--limit-request-line 0" part in the above myapp.service line but that does not fix it. Also tried putting it in a gunicorn.conf.py file as suggested by other posts and having myapp.service read from that, but that too did not help.

With 8040+ bytes, it does not even go to my Python app. It seems like gunicorn is rejecting it. With <8040 bytes, the POST call goes to my Python app, where I do some other processing on the uploaded file, etc.

How do I fix this so that I can upload files larger than 8040 bytes. Ideally I'd like to upload files of up to 8-10MB.